# Error uploading server certificate, error: MalformedCertificate: Unable to parse certificate. Please ensure the certificate is in PEM format

Tags: ssl, terraform, aws-acm

I am trying to use my organisation cert in my terraform code here.

crt.tf

```
resource "aws_iam_server_certificate" "acm_crt" {
    name = "acm_crt"
    certificate_body = "s3://cicd-storage/csr_keys_crts/crt.txt"
    private_key = "s3://cicd-storage/csr_keys_crts/csr.pem"
}
```

Error: Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

- aws_iam_server_certificate.acm_crt: 1 error(s) occurred:
- aws_iam_server_certificate.acm_crt: Error uploading server certificate, error: MalformedCertificate: Unable to parse certificate. Please ensure the certificate is in PEM format.

Comment: What makes you think you can specify an S3 path?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR S3 would be lil secured instead keeping certs under files..

Comment: Yes but the resource doesn't allow you to specify an S3 path like that. You must reference either the plain text directly in the resource or use the `file()` function to specify the contents of a local file.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Could you suggest any better solution instead of `file()`

Comment: No because there aren't any better options unfortunately.

Comment: Also you should probably be using ACM to upload server certificates instead of the deprecated IAM server certificates. It still doesn't allow you to specify a certificate and key pair in S3 though.